# InetSocketAddress vs InetAddress

Tags: java, network-programming

Can anyone please explain me is there is any difference between `InetAddress` and `InetSocketAddress` classes in java, and if there is a difference, please explain the same. I google-ed it up but I couldn't find anything explanatory.

Comment: Did you look at this? i find it quiet good
http://commitflame.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/comparing-inetaddress-and-inetsocketaddress-in-java/

Comment: What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand?

Comment: For what purpose are you intending to use either `InetAddress` or `InetSocketAddress`.  Do you have a specific use case in mind?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

An instance of an InetAddress consists of an IP address and possibly its corresponding host name

[InetSocketAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html)

This class implements an IP Socket Address (IP address + port number) It can also be a pair (hostname + port number), in which case an attempt will be made to resolve the hostname

Answer (score 11):

They represent different [OSI layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model):

- An `InetAddress` corresponds to the [Network Layer (Layer 3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_3:_Network_Layer) and is basically an IP address.
- A `InetSocketAddress` corresponds to the [Transport Layer (Layer 4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_4:_Transport_Layer) and consists of an IP address and a port number.